# How does Neo see unplugged humans in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

When Neo goes to meet the Oracle in *Matrix Reloaded*, he is first met by Seraph.

Here we are shown what Neo sees:

[image: Seraph is in gold, the rest is in green]

This is what Programs look like when he first realized that he is 'The One':

[image: Everything is green]

Is there anything on what unplugged humans look like in the Matrix through Neo's eyes?

Answer (score 3):

Neo appears to see unplugged humans as being made of green code, but only when he uses his "code vision" ability.

Interestingly, Trinity's code dulls as she loses consciousness (as she nears death), then becomes more vivid/glowing when Neo revives her.

Per the film script

> **Trinity:** *I had to...*
>
> **NEO:** *I know.*
>
> [A shudder runs through her body **as he sees the bullet inside**]

Comment: Was that what we see, or what Neo sees?

Comment: @KyloRen - There's every indication that this is What Neo sees, especially when we switch to his POV.